# Add http to a missing url in flutter

Tags: json, flutter, https, cdn, imageurl

Is there a way to add https extension hidden by CDN inside mapping in flutter?
As you can see in the picture below I'd need to add as link inside my model JSON but the https is hidden by the CDN.
How can I solve this issue in order to show up my image from that link?
Thank you in advance.

[image]

Fetch page for article

```
class ApiNewsPage {
  String baseUrl = "https://www.assofacile.it/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?_embed";

  Future<List> getNewsArticles() async {
    try {
      var response = await http.get(Uri.parse(baseUrl));
      //print(response);
      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        return jsonDecode(response.body);
      } else {
        return Future.error("Impossibile ricevere i dati, prova a controllare la connessione");
      }
      // ignore: non_constant_identifier_names
    } catch (SocketException) {
      return Future.error("Impossibile caricare gli articoli");
    }
  }
}
```

Model page for article

```
class Article{
  final String? urlImage;
  final String? title;
  final String? description;

  Article({
    required this.urlImage,
    required this.title,
    required this.description,
  });

  factory Article.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Article(
    urlImage: json["_embedded"]["wp:featuredmedia"][0]["link"],
    title: json["title"]["rendered"],
    description: json['content']['rendered'],
  );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = <String, dynamic>{};

    data['urlImage'] = urlImage;
    data['title'] = title;
    data['desciption'] = description;
    
    return data;
  }
}
```

Article content UI

```
SizedBox(
    height: 190,
    width: double.infinity,
    child: CachedNetworkImage(
      imageUrl: snapshot.data![i]["_embedded"]["wp:featuredmedia"][0]["link"],
                  fit: BoxFit.cover,
                  placeholder: (context, url) => Image.asset("assets/gif/shimmer.gif",
                  width: double.infinity,
                  height: 190,
                  fit: BoxFit.cover,
             ),
           errorWidget: (context, url, error) =>
      Image.asset("assets/images/unloadedImage.png", width: 250, height: 250),
   ),
),
```

Comment: uri = Uri.parse('//www.google.com'); uri1 = uri.replace(scheme: 'https'); print(uri); print(uri1);

Comment: Thank you, but I don't know where to add it exactly...

Answer (score 2):

You can create a simple method like bellow and verify before using the url that you need

```
 String checkIfUrlContainPrefixHttp(String url) {
    if (url.startsWith('http://') || url.startsWith('https://')) {
      return url;
    } else {
      return 'http://' + url;
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks William, I have a doubt, where do I need to add it exactly? I mean in Fetch page for article, in the Model page for article?

Comment: That's actually is more up to you, you can do it while parsing the json or directly on the widget creation, for example: imagemUrl: checkIfUrlContainPrefixHttp(URL)

Comment: Sorry William, I am new in Flutter, can you make an example in my code? I still don't get how to integrate this method...